# java.lang.IllegalAccessError in Selenium

Tags: java, exception, selenium, junit

I got this code from [BitMotif - Selenium Remote Control For Java — A Tutorial](http://www.bitmotif.com/selenium/selenium-remote-control-for-java-a-tutorial/)

```
package Practice;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;

public class TestMangaPanda
   extends TestCase
{
   private static final String MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MS = "6000";
   private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.bitmotif.com";
   private Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium( "localhost",
                                                    4444,
                                                    "*firefox",
                                                    BASE_URL);
    SeleniumServer seleniumServer;

    public void setUp() throws Exception
   {
      seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer();
      seleniumServer.start();
      selenium.start();
   }

   public void tearDown()
      throws Exception
   {
      selenium.stop();
      seleniumServer.stop();
   }

   public void testClickingLink()
      throws Exception
   {
      selenium.open(BASE_URL);
      selenium.click("link=Test Page For Selenium Remote Control");
      selenium.waitForPageToLoad(MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MS);

      String expectedTitle = "Bit Motif Â» Test Page For Selenium Remote Control";
      assertEquals(expectedTitle, selenium.getTitle());
   }
}
```

It is a basic Unit Testing using Selenium RC, but it keep on get this Exeption:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.LauncherUtils.getSeleniumResourceAsStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
>   from class org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.logVersionNumber(SeleniumServer.java:265)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.logStartupInfo(SeleniumServer.java:673)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.(SeleniumServer.java:229)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.(SeleniumServer.java:205)
>     at Practice.TestMangaPanda.setUp(TestMangaPanda.java:21)    at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)   at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)     at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)  at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)   at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)     at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Thank You :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to the jar files or the classes loaded at runtime. Can you please check whether you have latest Jar files in your class path? Try clean-up and build the project again.